# Call to function with settimeout disabled

Tags: jquery

```
function a() {

{...}

setTimeout(function(){ a(); }, 5000);

}

function b() {

{...}

a(); // CALL AND DISABLE SETTIMEOUT TO AVOID MULTI TASKS OF THE SAME FUNCTION

}
```

{Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).}

Answer (score 0):

```
function a(callSetTimeout) {

{...}
if(callSetTimeout !== false)
    setTimeout(function(){ a(); }, 5000);

}

function b() {

{...}

a(false); // CALL AND DISABLE SETTIMEOUT TO AVOID MULTI TASKS OF THE SAME FUNCTION

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When You want to call function "a()" then you can call it without any argument and when you want to stop calling then you can use clearTimeout()
for eg.

```
<button onclick="a()">Call My Function</button>
<button onclick="b()">End Up Calling</button>

<script>

var myVar;

function a(callSetTimeout) {
if(callSetTimeout !== false)
{
myVar=setTimeout(function(){ a(); }, 5000);
alert('Yes..I want to call it..');
}
else
{
alert('This is last time to call this function');
clearTimeout(myVar);
}
}

function b() {

a(false); // CALL AND DISABLE SETTIMEOUT TO AVOID MULTI TASKS OF THE SAME FUNCTION

}

</script>
```

You can call "b()" function when you wish to stop more calls to "a()"